# How to use Regex/ wilcard expression on step retrieve file with conditional filename PDI (Pentaho Data Integration)

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Iam a newbie using PDI 9.4 community edition,

I face little issue when trying to get data .xlsx from ftp to local with condititonal filename changed everyday from user,

So as you can see on my uploaded pict, I wish to get/retrieve **excel filename with range number between 01 and 31,**

for example, here it is the valid filename should be retrieve

**PM 11 Desember 2023.xlsx**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPvtB.png)

Please help and many thanks for your support.

I tried my best to retrieve filename as you can see my upload picture.

i really sorry for sort of my explanation, iam newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you need to match files of the type **01.xlsx** to **31.xlsx**, you'll need a regular expression of the type:

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(\.xlsx)
```

You have two groups in this expression:

```
(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])
```

and

```
(\.xlsx)
```

The first group has 3 options: `0[1-9]` matches 01 to 09, `[1-2][0-9]` matches 10 to 29, and `3[0-1]` matches 30 or 31.

The second group matches the extension .xlsx